# Regex a Block of Yaml Data

Tags: regex, dictionary, yaml

Im currently using regex101 to try and work out the following, id like to be able to capture a full items data for example name_template_2 and its associated description, define and write data

Here's my data model

```
templates:
  name_template:
    description: test_description
    define: yes
    write: true
  name_template_2:
    description: test_description2
    define: false
    write: true
```

I can capture the lines I need with the following

```
^[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]].*
```

and

```
^[[:space:]][[:space:]]name_template_2:
```

but I am unable to join both patterns together to filter just the key and data related to name_template_2. The more I read online the more I understand it less. Has anyone achieved this before or is there a much more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: ansible is being used

Comment: Perhaps like this with 2 capture groups? `^[^\S\n]{2}(name_template_2:)((?:\n[^\S\n]{4}\S.*)+)` https://regex101.com/r/jbnGpw/1

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I'll have a look through the capture groups and try and work out waist going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 2 capture groups:

```
^[^\S\n]{2}(name_template_2:)((?:\n[^\S\n]{4}\S.*)+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\n]{2}` Match 2 spaces without newlines
- `(name_template_2:)` Match the string and capture in **group 1**
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\n` Match a newline
    - `[^\S\n]{4}` Match 4 spaces without newlines
    - `\S.*` Match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line
  - `)+` Repeat the non capture group 1 or more times
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbnGpw/1)

Comment: Looks like this is what the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a structure-aware tool like [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) to manipulate YAML and not using regular expressions.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INPUT='
templates:
  name_template:
    description: test_description
    define: yes
    write: true
  name_template_2:
    description: test_description2
    define: false
    write: true
'

echo "$INPUT" | yq '{"name_template_2": .templates.name_template_2}'
```

**Output**

```yaml
name_template_2:
  description: test_description2
  define: false
  write: true
```

Comment: Doesn't give me the key included though

Comment: is it now as expected after my edit?